# How to run two loops in alternating fashion on Matlab?

Tags: matlab, loops, pde

I would like to use Matlab to compute two finite difference loops in such a manner that if we have two equations, let's say (1) and (2), it completes one step of (1) then solves (2) for one step then (1) for the next step and then (2) and so on and so forth.

To this end, I provide the parameters of my code below:

```
%% Parameters

L = 5; % size of domain 
T = 5; % measurement time
dx = 1e-2; % spatial step
dt = 1e-3; % time step
x0 = 0;
c = 1;

%%

t = 0:dt:T; % time vector
x = (0:dx:L)'; % spatial vector
nt = length(t);
nx = length(x);
Lx = (1/dx^2)*spdiags(ones(nx,1)*[1 -2 1],-1:1,nx,nx); % discrete Laplace operator
mu = dt/dx;
I = eye(nx,nx); % identity matrix
A = spdiags(ones(nx,1)*[-1 1 0],-1:1,nx,nx); % finite difference matrix
```

Then the first loop is given by

```
%% Finite Difference Equation (1)

% preallocate memory
u = zeros(nx,nt);
v = zeros(nx,nt);
% initial condition in time
u(:,1) = sinc((x-x0)/dx);
v(:,1) = sinc((x-x0)/dx);
for i = 1:nx-1
    u(:,i+1) = ((1/(c*dt))*I+(1/dx)*A)\((1/(c*dt))*u(:,i)+v(:,i));
end
```

and the second equation (2) is given by

```
%% Finite Difference Equation (2)

% preallocate memory
u = zeros(nx,nt);
v = zeros(nx,nt);
% final condition in time
u(:,nt) = sinc((x-x0)/dt);
% initial condition in space
for j = nt:-1:2
    v(:,j-1) = ((1/dx)*A+(1/(c*dt))*I)\((1/(c*dt))*v(:,j)
end
```

In the current format, Matlab will run the first loop `i = 1:nx-1` and then the second loop `j = nt:-1:2`.

But I want to run the two loops as follows: `i = 1`, then `j = nt`, then `i = 2`, then `j = nt-1` and so on and so forth. How should I code this?

Comment: are nt and nx the same? I think not, so how can you iterate in the same loop over two different size vectors?

Comment: @Ivan No. `nt = 5001` and `nx = 501`. Yes, that is a point. Perhaps it is possible if I through interpolating `t` onto `x`?

Comment: How are you supposed to do those iterations with just one loop as you want?

Comment: @Ivan Well, I thought of interpolation as one possibility. Probably not though. Another way could be to solve the first equation for ten values of `i` before solving one value of `j`, since `nt` is approximately ten times larger than `nx`. Can one code that?

Comment: yes, perhaps something like checking if (nt-i) mod 10 is equal to 0 and changing the j=((nt-i)/10)+1 value in that case (because the first time will be in the i=1, then 5001-1=5000 so you want to check the j=501). Just idea, havent try anything+

Comment: @Ivan I am trying that idea now, but what's strange is that running `for i = 1:nx-1
j = ((nt-i)/10)-1;
end` returns a single value.

Answer (score 1):

You can composite two loops like the following:

```
% define other variables and preallocations
j = nt;
for i = 1:nx-1 
    u(:,i+1) = ((1/(c*dt))*I+(1/dx)*A)\((1/(c*dt))*u(:,i)+v(:,i));
    v(:,j-1) = ((1/dx)*A+(1/(c*dt))*I)\((1/(c*dt))*v(:,j)
    j = j - 1;
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but interestingly, formulating it in this way produces an undesired `v` which has zeros everywhere (i.e. the method becomes unstable). Perhaps I need to arrange my initial conditions and such differently as there may be some overlap

Answer (score 1):

```
for i = 1:nx-1
    u(:,i+1) = ((1/(c*dt))*I+(1/dx)*A)\((1/(c*dt))*u(:,i)+v(:,i));
    %This if will be true once each 10 iterations
    if(mod((nt-i),10)==0)
        j=((nt-i)/10)+1;
        v(:,j-1) = ((1/dx)*A+(1/(c*dt))*I)\((1/(c*dt))*v(:,j);
    end
end
```

Don't really know if this will work, but making it more usable as you are trying my idea.

Comment: BTW are you sure about the index at `u` and `v`?, in both of them you are assigning in the all the rows at the column, and both of them have `nt`columns